# How to lower screen brightness on 2.4 inch monitor

Tags: raspbian, hardware, display, pi-zero, terminal

I have a 2.4 inch adafruit monitor for my rasberry pi, connected through the GPIO pins, and I have a problem with setting the screen brightness.

https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-2-4-pitft-hat-with-resistive-touchscreen-mini-kit/backlight-control

On the product page it says that the backlight can be controlled with the 18th GPIO pin, but I have no luck.

I am using the custom raspbian image that this monitor requires, downloaded from the adafruit website. Everything works fine except this.

So as the tutorial says, I have tried controlling it through the 18th pin, I have entered the following in the console:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "1" > /sys/class/backlight/soc\:backlight/brightness'
gpio -g mode 18 pwm
gpio pwmc 1000
gpio -g pwm 18 100
```

I think this code should lower the brighness to 100 out of 1023, which would be 9.7% brightness, but nothing happens.

No error is given, it's as if the command is doing nothing.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Some of the tft monitors require you to solder together a jumper labeled after gpio 18.

the jumper is typically two silver pads next to each other. put a solder blob on that connects both.

Comment: Doesn't that do the opposite? On the adafruit website it says that soldering it together actually disables the pin or did I read that incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution on Adafruit's forums.

https://forums.adafruit.com/viewtopic.php?f=50&t=127201&p=635357&hilit=gpio+18+pwm#p635357

They put it backwards on their website. Turn backlight off with

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "0" > /sys/class/backlight/soc\:backlight/brightness'
```

Then you can control with gpio 18.

```
gpio -g mode 18 pwm
gpio pwmc 1000
gpio -g pwm 18 100
```